# I cant get my pods to communicate using a service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

When I try using a service to read from my backend (written in ASP.NET Core) in my front (in Angular). I can read this screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHdbK.png) in the browser console and it doesn't get the information from the API pod.

I have two kubernetes deployment and each one has a service, they are created by this YAML file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dotnet-angular-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dotnet-angular-pod
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dotnet-angular-pod
        run: dotnet-angular-pod
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: dotnet-angular-container
          image: dotnet-angular
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
                requests:
                  memory: "64Mi"
                  cpu: "250m"
                limits:
                  memory: "512Mi"
                  cpu: "500m"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP 
--- 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: dotnet-angular-service
    labels: 
      run: dotnet-angular-pod
spec:
    ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 32000
    selector:
        app: dotnet-angular-pod
    type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dotnetangularapi-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dotnetangularapi-pod
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dotnetangularapi-pod
        run: dotnetangularapi-pod
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: dotnetangularapi-container
          image: dotnetangularapi
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
                requests:
                  memory: "64Mi"
                  cpu: "250m"
                limits:
                  memory: "512Mi"
                  cpu: "500m"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: ASPNETCORE_URLS
              value: http://+:80   
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: dotnetangularapi-service
    labels: 
      run: dotnetangularapi-pod
spec:
    ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 31000

    selector:
        app: dotnetangularapi-pod
    type: NodePort
---
```

In my Angular app when I call the backend I write `http://dotnetangularapi-service/demo` the controller I want to access is DemoController.cs thus the /demo.

I can't understand why the browser sends an ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVE and I can't even understand what the second error means.

Comment: Your browser isn't running inside the Kubernetes cluster, and your browser application can't resolve the Service hostnames.  You need to set up an Ingress and call the API through that.

Comment: @DavidMaze But my frontend isn't running through the browser is it ? I thought it was only linked back to the browser throught the service. Should i have used an ingress to link from the back to the front or from the bowser to the front? I don't really understand